# Javascript convert array of objects to an array with only specific keys with ES6

Tags: javascript

I have the following array

```
const array = [{name:'one', value:1},{name:'two'},{name:'three', value:3}]
```

What i want is to get

```
const finalarr = [1,3]
```

That is get an array of values with key value

So i have tried

```
const finalarr = arr.map(obj=>obj.value)
```

The above returns `[1, undefined, 3];`

I have also tried

```
const finalarr = arr.map(obj => {
       if (obj.value) {
         return obj.value;
       }
    })
```

but i still get `[1, undefined,3]`

How can i adjust this to only return the values of objects with a key value to eliminate the undefined key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `reduce` because the function `map` returns an array with the same length of the source array.

```
const finalarr = arr.reduce((a, {value}) => {
    if (value) a.push(value);
    return a;
}, []);
```

**Important:** your approach is skipping the objects with values equal to zero `0`.

*Example*

```js
const arr = [{name:'one', value:1},{name:'two'},{name:'three', value:3}];
const finalarr = arr.reduce((a, {value}) => {
    if (value) a.push(value);
    return a;
}, []);
console.log(finalarr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce

```js
const array = [{name:'one;', value:1},{name:'two'},{name:'three', value:3}]

let final = array.reduce((op,{value})=>{
  if(typeof value !== 'undefined'){
    op.push(value)
  }
  return op
},[])


console.log(final)
```

map used to map complete array back with changed values it doesn't skip value you can use map and filter for you purpose

```js
const arr = [{name:'one', value:1},{name:'two'},{name:'three', value:3}]

const finalarr = arr.filter(({value})=>typeof value !== 'undefined').map(({value})=> value)


console.log(finalarr)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Array `.map` method will return another array with the exact same size of the original array.

If you want a result with different size, you cannot do it with pure `.map` only.

What you can do is to first `.filter` out objects without `.value` property:

```js
const array = [{name:'one', value:1},{name:'two'},{name:'three', value:3}]

const result = array
        .filter(obj => typeof obj.value !== 'undefined')
        .map(obj => obj.value);
        
console.log(result);
```

Otherwise, you can also use `.reduce`:

```js
const array = [{name:'one', value:1},{name:'two'},{name:'three', value:3}]

const result = array.reduce((arr, obj) => {

  if (typeof obj.value !== 'undefined')
    arr.push(obj.value);
    
  return arr;
  
}, []);
        
console.log(result);
```